# TextView android:ellipsize in ActionBar with two imageButtons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

I have tried to get ellipsize to work on my title but as you can see in the image it set the ... before the menu button and not before the two added imagebuttons.

Activity code to set title:

```
// set title
TextView mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.group_post_title);
mTitle.setText(title);
```

Title XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_post_title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:text="@string/group_post" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/group_post_comment_add"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/group_post_status_view"
        android:background="@drawable/title_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_grouppost"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/group_post_status_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/group_post_status"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/group_post_reload"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/title_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/reload"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_refresh" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style code:

```
<style name="title">
      <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
      <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
      <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
      <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
      <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ham.png

Comment: If anybody is interested i found the solution:
Add a LinearLayout around the "things" to the right.
Give it a id.
Use android:layout_toLeftOf on the title TextView to the id given on the LinearyLayout and wupti the title use android:ellipsize correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Add a `LinearLayout` around the "things" to the right. Give it an `id`. Use `android:layout_toLeftOf` on the title `TextView` to the `id` given on the `LinearyLayout` and wupti the title use `android:ellipsize` correct.

Comment: I tried making something of that comment you reverred to. But it doesn't really make sense to me. (I'm not an android hacker, so it may well be me!) Maybe you can edit this answer to show the important bits of your code.